# Convergence/Divergence $(-1)^n n^2$ and $(-1)^n \frac{6}{n+7}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to know why the series $(-1)^n n^2$, $n \in\mathbb{N}$ doesn 't converge and why $(-1)^n \frac{6}{n+7}$ converges.

Wolfram Alpha would just tell me that the first series doesn't converge and for the second series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6(-1)^n}{n+7} = \frac{1}{70}(420 \log (2)-319)$$, but I can't start anything with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Leibniz to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{6(-1)^n}{n+7}$ is convergent.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n n^2$ is divergent, since $((-1)^nn^2)$ does not converge to $0.$

Comment: The sequence $(\frac{2n^2+1}{6n^2+5n+4})$ is convergent with limit $\frac{2}{6}$, but the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n^2+1}{6n^2+5n+4}$ is divergent, since $(\frac{2n^2+1}{6n^2+5n+4})$ does not converge to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first diverges because the $n$th term doesn't $\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. The second converges by the alternating series test.